# STM32F3 High Resolution Timer

Tags: microcontroller, stm32

I'm looking to develop an ultrasonic time-of-flight (ToF) sensor and have been looking at high speed timing circuits. Many versions use the TDC7200, but ST offers the [STM32F334](http://www.st.com/en/microcontrollers/stm32f334.html?querycriteria=productId=LN1820) which has a high-resolution timer with apparent **217ps resolution**.

What I'm wondering whether this timer can actually be used to *measure time with 217ps between each count value* (assuming it's run at maximum clock rate)?

Does anyone have experience using this microcontroller's high-resolution timer like this?

Comment: What does the reference manual say?

Answer (score 0):

According to the reference manual it should be possible:

High-Resolution Timer (HRTIM) : For control and monitoring purposes, the timer has also timing measure capabilities and links to built-in ADC and DAC converters. Last, it features light-load management mode and
is able to handle various fault schemes for safe shut-down purposes. --[page 626](http://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/reference_manual/71/30/2e/f3/20/5b/46/c1/DM00093941.pdf/files/DM00093941.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.DM00093941.pdf#page=626)

The timing unit has the capability to capture the counter value, triggered by internal and
external events. The purpose is to:
• measure events arrival timings or occurrence intervals --[page 641](http://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/reference_manual/71/30/2e/f3/20/5b/46/c1/DM00093941.pdf/files/DM00093941.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.DM00093941.pdf#page=641)